# TabPane, changing color of tab-header-area

Tags: javafx-8, tabpanel

I want to change color or set picture in pointed area:

[image]

Ive read on css reference guide that TabPane has a substructure

```
tab-header-area — StackPane
headers-region — StackPane
tab-header-background — StackPane
control-buttons-tab — StackPane
tab-down-button — Pane
arrow — StackPane
tab — Tab
tab-label — Label
tab-close-button — StackPane
tab-content-area — StackPane
```

So i tried to do it somehow with CSS but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: green ;
}
```

seems to work for me

Comment: do You know maybe how can I set jpg picture from source folder instead of color?

Comment: Ive tried `-fx-background-image: "CardsTableInfoBackground.jpg";`  but no.

Comment: It's expecting a [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl) (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)). So you need `-fx-background-image: url("CardsTableInfoBackground.jpg");`. The path is relative to the CSS file.

Comment: somehow I can construct proper path. CSS is in `com.root.tomaszm` and jpg is in source folder named Files. Till this time simple `"imagename.jpg"` worked. so I dont get it.